# Show that $P(A \cap B) \geq P(A)\cdot P(B)$

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve the following:

Show that $P(A \cap B) \geq P(A)\cdot P(B)$ if $P(A) = P(B)$ when P(A) and P(B) might be either independent or dependent events.

What I've managed to show:
$P(A | B) = P(B | A)\frac{P(A)}{P(B)} = P(B | A)$

If they are independent:

$P(A | B) = \frac{P(A)P(B)}{P(B)} = P(A) = P(B)$

$P(A \cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$

If they are dependent:

$P(A | B)P(B) \geq P(A)\cdot P(B)$

$P(A | B) \geq P(A)$

Can I show that this last expression is always true, or do I need more information?

Comment: This isn't always true.  Suppose $A,B$ are disjoint events.  For an explicit example suppose you are tossing a fair coin and $A$ is the event "you get Heads" and $B$ is the event "you get Tails".

Comment: Hey, not really. The exercise is explicitly asking to show that $P(A|B) \geq P(A)$ is always true (given P(A) = P(B)), but I can't seem to figure it out (or the exercise might be giving away too little information)

Comment: @CajM lulu's counterexample seems valid to me. The exercise is giving away too little information.